# Why doesn't 'operator<<(cout, double)' work?

Tags: c++, operators, overloading, operator-keyword

I'm studying overloaded operators. 
I don't get the difference between  using the `<<`-operator on a `double` / an `std::string`.

```
int main()
{
    double a = 12;
    string s = "example";

    operator<<(cout, a); //doesn't work
    cout.operator<<(a);  //works

    operator<<(cout, s); //works
    cout.operator<<(s);  //doesn't work   
}
```

Why aren't `operator<<(cout, a)` and `cout.operator<<(s);` working?

Answer (score 6):

Because that operator is defined as a member function, not as a free function.

Operators can be overloaded in those two ways, which when used with regular operator syntax will be transparent to the user. However, when using explicit syntax, you have to use the one specific to the actual function definition.

This example shows the difference in practice:

```
class Stream {
    Stream& operator<<(Inside);
};

Stream& operator<<(Stream&, Outside);
```

For `std::string`, `Outside` way is used. For `double`, `Inside` is.

Comment: Return value for inside still should be `Stream&`.

Answer (score 4):

You can define operators in two different ways, as a member of a class and as free-standing function taking two arguments.

The operator accepting a double value is implemented as a member function of `std::ostream`, see [cpp reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt). You'll notice that there is no overload for `char const*` or `std::string` provided. These are defined [separately](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2), as free-standing functions, among some others.

Those operators defined as members (only!) work with the `cout.operator<<(argument)` notation, the free-standing ones with the two-argument variant.

However, all these differences are hidden away if you use the operators as they are intended:

```
std::cout << whatEver;
```

Answer (score 2):

Because a non-class operator << for the types std::basic_ostream & and double (or const double &) is not defined in C++.

Such an operator that takes one argument of the type double is declared in the class std::basic_ostream as a member function.

```
basic_ostream<charT, traits>& operator<<(double f);
```

For objects of the type std::string the operator is declared as a stand-alone (non a class member) function the following way

```
template<class charT, class traits, class Allocator>
basic_ostream<charT, traits>&
operator<<(basic_ostream<charT, traits>& os,
const basic_string<charT, traits, Allocator>& str);
```

Answer (score 2):

`std::basic_ostream` provides some `<<` implementations (for basic types) as member functions. For other types (such as for `std::basic_string`), `operator <<` is implemented as a free function. That's how the standard specifies it.

This is only a problem if you're invoking the operator using explicit function call notation (like in your code). The natural way to use it is using operator notation (`cout << x`), where the problem does not happen, as both member and free functions can be invoked by it.

Answer (score 0):

You are using operator not in the right way.

operators may be implemented as member functions or non-member.

when running

```
 cout.operator <<(a);
 cout << a;
 cout.operator <<(s);
 cout << s;
```

you are calling the class operarator implementation;

but when you call

```
operator<<(cout, a);
```

where is the implementation ? o_O

**Working example** tested vc++13 & [gcc(here)](https://onlinegdb.com/SkeSOih-S)

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   int number = 13;
   float pi = 3.13f;
   double dp = 2.23233;


   cout << "number: " << number << endl;
   cout << "pi: " << pi << endl;
   cout << "double: " << dp << endl << endl;


   cout.operator <<(number) << endl;
   cout.operator <<(pi) <<  endl;
   cout.operator <<(dp);
}
```

Comment if need member or non-member implementation of example type.